# How to avoid creating duplicate nodes when ID is not known

Tags: java, neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I am using Neo4J to save events from Git-lab web hooks.
An example of the data can be found here https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/web_hooks/web_hooks.md#push-events
One of the nodes is an Author {name,email}

Here the email is the natural unique id.
In Hibernate(JPA) there is an annotation called @Id that i could set on the Author field email ([ref to docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/ogm/4.1/reference/en-US/html/ogm-neo4j.html#_entities_4)).
How can I make Neo4J OGM to persist/merge based on email instead of it's id?

[image]

Comment: Can you please give us the actual code you are using to create your relations?

Comment: Here is the complete application: https://github.com/sofusalbertsen/GitlabPlugin

Answer (score 0):

One of the fastes/easiest solution would be to use [constraints](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-constraints.html#query-constraints-unique-nodes):

`Create CONSTRAINT ON (a:Author) ASSERT a.email IS UNIQUE`

This way, neo4j will ensure constraint is respected, and you don't have to implement uniqueness on server side, since database is doing it.

Comment: If I make a constraint, i just get an error when I try to persist.
The problem is not the DB side, but how the OGM framework can be tweaked to merge instead of creating a new node.

Answer (score 0):

In an ETL tool you would reasonably expect to able to define your source keys/identities. Neo4j OGM is not really an ETL tool, but if you want to use it as a data importer, you have a couple of options.

The first is to manage the key-mappings yourself. Of course, this may be impractical, depending on volumes and other considerations. The second is always try to fetch a given object from the graph via its email address before saving any item from your event feed.

Comment: ETL tool?
What i want is an easy way to define how entities are similar.
Right now, as I can read from the documentation, the only thing that determines similarity is @ GraphId, that is limited to Long.
I need something like the @ Id from JPA.

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of comments.

1. `Administrator` seems to be the value of the `name` property, not the `email` property. Are you sure the 3 `Administrator` nodes in you image actually have the same `email` property value? To make the neo4j Browser show the `email` values, [set the caption](http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser/#_styling_neo4j_browser_visualization) for the `Author` nodes to `email` instead of `name`.
2. Aside from the above, it looks like you have already tried this Cypher query, but are getting what seem to be duplicates:

   ```
   MERGE (n:Author {name: {name}, email: {email}})
   RETURN n
   ```

   That could be explained if it is possible for the input data to contain multiple names for the same email address. In that case, the following query should prevent "duplicate" `Author` nodes. If an `Author` with the parameterized email address already exists (regardless of its `name` value), it just returns the existing node (without changing its `name`); otherwise, it creates a new `Author` node with the parameterized `email` and `name` properties. This solution would mean that only the first `name` encountered for an `email` address will be stored in the DB.

   ```
   MERGE (n:Author {email: {email}})
   ON CREATE SET n.name = {name}
   RETURN n
   ```

Comment: The Author has identical email and name in the example.
I know how i could do it using cypher, but then i (as you) would have to write all the persistence code myself, and therefore the purporse of an OGM framework is lost. What I want is an equivalent to JPA's @Id.
I updated the question to highlight this matter.